# Is it possible to do an API without Endpoint?

Tags: api

I have this question because of a discussion at work, one person says yes and another person says no, what is the right answer?

Comment: The person saying an endpoint is not required might be misunderstanding what an endpoint is. Ask that person to explain how you can connect to an API with no endpoint. The endpoint being an address.

Comment: What about a SOAP API? The type of API wasn't exactly specified.

Comment: There are alternatives to "endpoints" in the other protocols or standards?

Comment: is the concept of API in General @DrewKennedy

Comment: The Google definition of API: "a set of functions and procedures allowing the creation of applications that access the features or data of an operating system, application, or other service." For REST you need endpoints as others have stated. But for an API that's used to aid in writing an application, no, you don't need Endpoints. It's a pretty broad topic.

Comment: Exactly, the problem is that I have an ETL that is executed from a Cron, (Anypoint Mulesoft), this person says that it does comply with the API concept because the cron consumes the ETL

Comment: I would not say the ETL or the Cron are APIs. APIs do not consume data except for what they are given.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lets take `REST` API's for instance as the example here.

An `Endpoint` is an address that you *call* in order to GET / DELETE / PUT or POST data TO or FROM the service that is providing the API.

*Imagine an Endpoint to be like a phone-number.*

If you call `911` someone will likely answer with **"Hey, whats your emergency?"**

But if you call `000091100000` the likelihood of someone answering with **"Hey, whats your emergency?"** would probably decrease.

So, an endpoint is usually what you would refer to as the "address" to an API-function.

Eg. https://api.yourDomain.com/users/get/details/query?age=25

Comment: and in the other protocols?